# how to merge three rows into one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to change output of the sql query  from 1 to 2

```
1:- user_id     subject name     marks 
    1001        maths            67
    1001        pyhsics          78
    1001        chemistry        87
    1002        maths            89
    1002        physics          56
    1002        chemistry        76

2:- user_id     maths      physics     chemistry
    1001        67         78          87
    1002        89         56          76
```

I'm  expecting sql query

Comment: Not clear what your after

Answer (score 1):

Use `crosstab` (pivot tables) to turn rows into columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
 'SELECT user_id, subject_name, marks FROM t' 
) AS ct(user_id int, maths int, physics int, chemistry int);
```

Another option, with a slightly different purpose, is to use conditional aggregates with `FILTER`:

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  SUM(marks) FILTER (WHERE subject_name = 'maths') AS maths,
  SUM(marks) FILTER (WHERE subject_name = 'physics') AS physics,
  SUM(marks) FILTER (WHERE subject_name = 'chemistry') AS chemistry
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/kgerVYIX)